# How to delete a file with bad characters via adb shell?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

Running ls in the directory reports the filename as being `-\356esk+\256\ stolet+\241\ 2.d+\241l-Den\ po\ Mnichovu.srt`.

Autocomplete changes it to `-�esk+� stolet+� 2.d+�l-Den po Mnichovu.srt`.

I've tried (unsuccessfully) through `adb shell`

- specifying the file with `rm -fr ./-�esk+�\ stolet+�\ 2.d+�l-Den\ po\ Mnichovu.srt`
- deleting all the files with `rm -fr ./*`
- deleting the directory recursively with `rm -fr Download`

All of the command just give me an "No such file or directory" error. Is there a way to remove it without nuking my phone?  Thank you in advance for any feedback and suggestions

Comment: Were the files created with that strange file-name or did the characters change later? May be this is just an indicator for a problem on file-system level. make sure you have rebooted your phone.

Comment: I believe that the file was created with the strange file-name. I suspect that it should be "České století 2.díl-Den po Mnichovu.srt". The phone has been rebooted.